# Requesting FOREX data through IB API (Invalid destination exchange specified)

Tags: java, matlab, tws

I am trying to connect to Interactive Broker's API to request historical FOREX data. However, every-time I try requesting data I get "Invalid destination exchange specified". What am I doing wrong? Here's my code (doing it with Matlab at the moment):

```
 ib = ibtws('',7496);

ibContract = ib.Handle.createContract;
ibContract.symbol = 'EUR.USD';
ibContract.secType = 'CASH';
ibContract.exchange = 'SMART';
ibContract.primaryExchange = 'ISLAND';
ibContract.currency = 'USD';

startdate = floor(now) - 10;
enddate = floor(now)-10;

d = history(ib,ibContract,startdate,enddate)  


close(ib)
```

Comment: With `ibtws('',7496)`  you connect to an IB Trader Workstation running on your *local machine*. Do you have such an IB Trader Workstation running, or do you want to connect to some other server? If that is the case, you'll have to specify its IP adress. This is documented in the [help page of `ibtws`](http://mathworks.com/help/trading/ibtws.html).

Comment: Yup, TWS is on my local machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- The symbol is EUR.
- The currency is USD.
- The exchange is IDEALPRO, no primary exchange.
- The secType is still CASH, that part is right.

I don't know how matlab works, but I wouldn't close the connection until the data has been returned to a callback function.

Here's a link to the newest docs.  http://interactivebrokers.github.io/tws-api/basic_contracts.html#cash

Comment: I was searching for that link for so long. Thank you!!

Comment: Do you happen to know if there is a whole database somewhere with all these info for stocks, indexes, futures, forex etc? With all the symbols, currency, exchange, secType etc.

Comment: @LuisCruz https://www.interactivebrokers.com/en/index.php?f=1563  Every broker usually has a page with available products.  [This one is searchable.](https://pennies.interactivebrokers.com/cstools/contract_info/v3.9/index.php?)